# If jQuery Ajax handles serialization, why do we do it

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have read that the jQuery Ajax methods serialize user input automatically in the background. Is that true? In what cases?

Then why do we have to every write our code like this:

```
$( "form" ).on( "submit", function( event ) {
  event.preventDefault();
  $( this ).serialize();
});
```

Comment: I think what it is talking about is if we pass data as an object like `{myparam:value}` then ajax serializes it to `myparam=value`

Comment: @ArunPJohny OP wants to know why to serialize explicitly when jQuery does for you

Comment: Yes @Pilot I want to know exactly that. In what cases does jquery automatically serialize data and in what cases or requirements should we do it manually.

Comment: @Thomasmkov you need to serialize when you want to pass data to ajax call as Arun sir said

Comment: Anything other than a string will be turned into a valid query string by ajax. See `processData` and `traditional` options of `$.ajax`. You may want to handle serialization differently, upfront, which is where using `serialize()` and `$.param()` come into play. Also, that and the fact that serialize() and serializeArray() are convenience methods to serialize whole forms, where as in other cases users might be passing individual form element values.

Comment: @userabuser when you say handle serialization differently, what do you mean?

Comment: Setting the `traditional` param to true on $.ajax builds the query string as it was done so prior to jQuery 1.4, known as shallow serialization, versus deep.